# BigQuery Storage API cannot read from a temporary table created by ordered (ORDER BY) queries

Tags: api, google-bigquery, storage

Google's BigQuery Storage API can read from *temporary tables* created from basic queries involving only SELECT, FROM and WHERE.

What I'm seeing is that when you use an ORDER BY statement to retrieve an ordered set of rows, the temporary table that is created is unreadable from the BigQuery storage API.

Have a look at the code example below:

Let's take this query:

```
sql = """SELECT name FROM `bigquery-public-data.usa_names.usa_1910_current` LIMIT 1000"""
```

If you run it with this BigQuery python API code:

```
bq_client = bigquery.Client("myproject") ## << Change to your project

query_job = bq_client.query(
    sql,
    location='US')  

project_id = query_job.destination.project
dataset_id = query_job.destination.dataset_id
table_id = query_job.destination.table_id

print("Destination table: " + project_id + "." + dataset_id + "." + table_id)
```

... then you obtain the destination table.

From here, you can pass this destination table to the BigQuery Storage API to obtain the results using RPC:

```
client = bigquery_storage_v1beta1.BigQueryStorageClient()

table_ref = bigquery_storage_v1beta1.types.TableReference()
table_ref.project_id = project_id
table_ref.dataset_id = dataset_id
table_ref.table_id = table_id

read_options = bigquery_storage_v1beta1.types.TableReadOptions()
read_options.selected_fields.append("name")

parent = "projects/{}".format(project_id)
session = client.create_read_session(
    table_ref, parent, table_modifiers=modifiers, read_options=read_options
)  # API request.

reader = client.read_rows(
    bigquery_storage_v1beta1.types.StreamPosition(stream=session.streams[0])
)

rows = reader.rows(session)
```

This works fine.

Now change the query in `sql= <yourquery>` to be

```
sql = """SELECT name FROM `bigquery-public-data.usa_names.usa_1910_current` ORDER BY name ASC LIMIT 1000"""
```

and you'll get the following error from the BigQuery Storage API part of the code:

`Table 'myproject:mydataset.temptable' has a storage format that is not supported.`

This means that the ORDER BY statement in the query added some manner of complexity that made the temporary table unreadable to the storage API.

Question:
1) Any thoughts on how to resolve this, or is it a real limitation of the storage API at this point?
2) If the ORDER BY creates a problem, what is the full extent of queries 
that create unreadable temporary tables for the storage API?

Comment: What are the sizes of the result sets? AFAIK, this has to do with the size of the temporary table, not ORDER BY. There's a threshold of about 100 MB before the BigQuery Storage API can read from a temporary table. This can be worked around by explicitly setting a destination table in the query.

Comment: If you run the code examples above, you'll find the same result:  Regardless of the size of the data, by adding ORDER BY to the query you cannot read from the temporary table anymore.  Indeed it works when you explicitly create a temporary table as destination, but not with the implicitly created table.

Comment: When I run the code examples (setting modifiers to None as this was not defined), I first get the error `400 there was an error creating the session: the table has a storage format that is not supported` without ORDER BY set and then with ORDER BY set I get `400 The following selected fields do not exist in the table schema: name`.

Answer (score 1):

We can read from temporary tables which are created by queries like order by, join etc. using bigquery_storage.BigQueryReadClient. Below is the working code.
I have created the temp table using join.

```
from google.cloud.bigquery_storage import BigQueryReadClient
from google.cloud.bigquery_storage import types, ReadRowsResponse

bqclient = bigquery.Client(credentials=credentials, project=your_project_id,)
client = bigquery_storage.BigQueryReadClient(credentials=credentials)

try:
    import fastavro
except ImportError:  
    fastavro = None

sql = """SELECT s.id, s.name, d.dept  FROM sbx-test.EMP.emp01 s join sbx-test.EMP.dept d 
on s.id = d.id"""
query_job = bqclient.query(sql)

project_id = query_job.destination.project
dataset_id = query_job.destination.dataset_id
table_id = query_job.destination.table_id

table = "projects/{}/datasets/{}/tables/{}".format(
    project_id, dataset_id, table_id
)
requested_session = types.ReadSession()
requested_session.table = table
requested_session.data_format = types.DataFormat.AVRO

requested_session.read_options.selected_fields = ["name", "dept"]

parent = "projects/{}".format(project_id)
session = client.create_read_session(
    parent=parent,
    read_session=requested_session,
    max_stream_count=1,
)
reader = client.read_rows(session.streams[0].name)
rows = reader.rows(session)

names = set()
depts = set()
for row in rows:
    names.add(row["name"])
    depts.add(row["dept"])
    
print("Got unique employees {} and departments {}".format(names, depts))
```